# Selecting a value in an input field and then populate another field with corresponding data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a form that has a an input field with a data list that is getting data from php here is that snippt of code.

```
<input type=text list=jobs style='font-size:21px;height: 40px;' class='form-control'  name="Code">
    <datalist id=jobs>
      <?php foreach ($this->Products as $a) {
                     echo '<option value=' . $a["Code"] . '>' . $a["Code"] . " - " . $a["Name"] . ' </option>';
                            }?>
    </datalist>
```

when you select of of the records that is produced the field just shows the $Code so what i want is underneath is a read only input field which shows the $Name for the selected item.

how can this be achieved in javascript/jquery

Comment: take a look at the [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a label:

```
echo '<label>' + $a["Name"] + ': ';
echo '<option value=' . $a["Code"] . '>' . $a["Code"] . " - " . $a["Name"] . ' </option>';
echo '</label>';
```